# Possible valuations on polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Suppose $k$ be a field and we consider polynomial ring over $k$, $k[x_1,x_2]$. Let $f\in k[x_1,x_2]$. We define a (non Archimedian valuation) map $v:k[x_1,x_2]\longrightarrow \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ (here $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ has lexicographic order)in the following way:
Suppose $f=a_0+a_1x_2+\cdots +a_nx_2^n$, where $a_i\in k[x_1]$ and $a_n\neq 0$. We define

$v(f)=(v_{x_1}(a_n),n)$, where $v_{x_1}$ is defined by the degree of $a_n$.

We can also define another valuation on $k[x_1,x_2]$ by writing $f$ as polynomial in $x$ and defining similar way.

My question is what are the possible valuations on $k[x_1,x_2]$? Is there a general procedure to determine all possible valuations on $k[x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n]$?

Comment: I know very little about this, but recently attended some talks by M. Spivakovsky where he talked about this problem. You might find the following paper useful: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Spivakovsky_Mark/publication/248295538_Valuations_in_Function_Fields_of_Surfaces/links/577b56e708aece6c20fbe40c.pdf I don't have my notes at hand, but once I do I'll see if I can write an answer with some content out of them. AFAIR (and from what I see in the above paper) there's been a lot of work for the surface case, while the problem for dimension 3 or higher is already very complicated.

Answer (score 2):

No, I suspect that there must be far too many valuations to have any hope of a simple classification like that. For example there are the orders of vanishing along all kinds of varieties in the plane, including infinitely near things (i.e., orders of vanishing of derivatives; or, vanishing along blowups). And that is just barely getting started. Now, I don't really know a whole lot about valuation theory, but that's my guess, that there are far too many valuations and kinds of valuations to have any hope of classifying them.

Perhaps you might be interested in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210265) that classifies all the valuations on the power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ and shows that the set of valuations has a natural tree structure (!!).

Comment: Can this be related to ordering of monomials in the polymoial rings?